# Bind a class list to Excel sheet using VSTO in c#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am using a list of class holding some data and I need to bind to a excel sheet in c# using VSTO. I have added VSTO package in VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Worksheet.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range?view=vsto-2017) property which returns a [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range(v=vs.110).aspx) object that represents a cell or a range of cells. The range object represents a cell, a row, a column, a selection of cells containing one or more contiguous blocks of cells, or a 3-D range.

The following code example demonstrates different ways to use the Range property to access a single cell or multiple cells:

```
private void CompareRangeUsage()
{                      
    Worksheet vstoWorksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(
        this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);
    // The following line of code specifies a single cell.
    vstoWorksheet.Range["A1"].Value2 = "Range 1";

    // The following line of code specifies multiple cells.
    vstoWorksheet.Range["A3", "B4"].Value2 = "Range 2";

    // The following line of code uses an Excel.Range for 
    // the second parameter of the Range property.
    Excel.Range range1 = vstoWorksheet.Range["C8"];
    vstoWorksheet.Range["A6", range1].Value2 = "Range 3";
}
```